# why does the BTNS_DROPDOWN style cause the whole toolbar to move down a couple pixels?

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I have a CToolbar and within it I have a button with style BTNS_BUTTON|BTNS_DROPDOWN. I would like to make it a split button, so the left side of the button is a button, and the right side has a drop down menu.

To complete this, I create the button then I call ::SendMessage like so:

```
::SendMessage( hwndForButton, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS );
```

This works great and creates the split button, but also has the ill-effect of moving down the toolbar a couple pixels. If I don't send the message, then I still have the issue (and I don't have the split button anymore).

If I change the style of the button to BTNS_BUTTON|BTNS_WHOLEDROPDOWN then I don't have an issue, although I also don't have the split button.

Any clue as to what could be going wrong here? I figure there is a margin that is applied to a BNTS_DROPDOWN and it is causing the toolbar to move down.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? - I'm getting exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Nope, never did solve this. I ended up just moving the window a couple pixels to correct the layout. This is less than ideal and may cause the toolbar to look funny on high DPI set ups.

Answer (score 1):

Well this question is *very* old indeed but since it appears at the very top of google results on the topic and for future reference browsing a little further it seems that there is one workaround (quoted from http://www.ureader.com/msg/1484852.aspx):

"Don't know why, but the problem rise when
I set the the BTNS_DROPDOWN style from the beginning. I've if add the
buttons without any of the set to BTNS_DROPWN and in the next line I
use TB_SETBUTTONINFO to change the style, everything works fine."

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with setting the BTNS_DROPDOWN style, on a CToolBar extension, which was being made more apparent when DPI scaling was above 100%.

floyd73's link seems to be broken, but having tried to set the dropdown style separately through setbuttoninfo didn't work.

The solution we found was to re-scale the toolbar after the styles have been set to take into account the new button sizes using SetSizes():

```
auto imgList = GetToolBarCtrl().GetImageList();
if (imgList)
{
    //Scale toolbar buttons to fit the correct scaled icons
    CSize buttonSize(GetToolBarCtrl().GetButtonSize());
    CSize imageSize;
    ImageList_GetIconSize(imageList, &imageSize.cx, &imageSize.cy);

    SetSizes(buttonSize, imageSize);
}
```

We stuck this into a NormalSize() function to use at the end of any custom toolbar setup, which should allow us to catch any other funny resizing business with button styles.

Hope this helps anyone still facing the same issue.